# E3 Ubuntu Steps for Nginx proxy pass a port to port 80

Tags: server, nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy

I'm running a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 server using Amazon E3. I edited `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` to read:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

}
```

Then I restart the `nginx` server `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`

Then double check to make sure that my simple application is being server on port 8080.

But I still don't see the app when I go to the IP.

Is there another step I'm missing like adding a security rule somewhere?

Comment: I think you need to change "default server" and "server_name" to your actual site name. I doubt your suerver is "server_name_.com"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen `server_name _;` is a special "match all" name.  That isn't the issue.  The `default_server` items are going to indicate this is the site to serve when no other configs 'match' other configured servers.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride nuke your browser cache, or use Curl to test.  Browsers cache results, so you might not see the 'site' if your cache is still caching things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config looks valid. So you should check:

1. iptables on you Ubuntu instance (iptables -L -n).
2. Security group. Access on port 80 should be allowed for you IP, or your subnet, or everyone (0.0.0.0/0).
3. Network ACL. As with security group it should allow access on port 80. They work on subnet level.

Last two make sense only if you're running your instance in VPC.

Comment: They need to erase their cache as well - in case their browser is affecting the data (which it will be)

Comment: On laptop at home instead of work PC so cache is cleared. Here is the output of iptables -L -n http://pastebin.com/vH5Z8CLJ Doesn't seem to be in line with what it should be.  Is there a simple command I can run to add port 80?

Comment: That is clear table with no rules. Such configuration allows ALL traffic, so that's not your problem. You should check VPC configuration then.

Comment: @SergeyKovalev for peoples future reference it was the VPC issue. I went to list with E3 instances, clicked on the security group and added port 80. By default only port 22 was open.